# header function does not work in php

Tags: php, mysql, session

why header function does not work here ? 
**it work successfully on localhost**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        require_once('models/config.php');  require_once('models/mysql.class.php');
        $username=$_POST['username'];
        $password=$_POST['password'];       
        $obj_Pharmacies=new mysql();     
        $sql_query="SELECT * FROM `sellers_accounts` WHERE`user_name`='$username' AND `password`='$password'";
        $obj_Pharmacies->Execute($sql_query);
        if($obj_Pharmacies->Execute($sql_query)){

            $Pharmacies=$obj_Pharmacies->GetRows();         
            $cookie_seller_name=$Pharmacies[0]['name'];         
            $cookie_seller_user_name=$Pharmacies[0]['user_name'];
            $Pharmacies_number=count($Pharmacies);
            if($Pharmacies_number>=1){
                //$_SESSION['sellerName']=$cookie_seller_name;
                setcookie('sellerName', $cookie_seller_name, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
                //$_SESSION['sellerUsername']=$cookie_seller_user_name;
                //$_SESSION['sellerName'];
                header("location:plans.php");
          }     
        }


    } 
?>
```

Comment: Have a look at this article [set cookie header missing](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1058)

Comment: Enable error reporting. Most likely there is a warning (`headers already sent ...`) and you just don't see it.

Comment: it works successfully on localhost and my host although when i uploaded the code on my client host it does not work

Comment: how can i enalble error reporting ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


using this ??

Comment: Its sure got do something with dependencies.check all the dependencies for the script.i.e dependencies for client.

Comment: :  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ahmedessamelden/public_html/login.php:29) in 

this is the  output

Comment: There you have the cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
$base_url =  "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
   $redirect_url = $base_url."plans.php";
   header("location:$redirect_url");
```